# PostgreSQL decrease performance after migration

Tags: sql, postgresql, upgrade, database-performance

After PostgreSQL database server v9.3 migration to v9.6 I noticed a decreace in the performance of the entire system. The config parameters are the same as in v9.3 taking in to account the next parameters:

1. shared_buffers = 10000MB
2. work_men= 64MB
3. maintenance_work_men = 1024MB

Also I tried to monitor some resources, and this is the result

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        385M        4.5G         10G         26G 19G
Swap:          3.0G          0B        3.0G
```

Also when I run some queries the server internally launches queries like these ones:

```
select typname from pg_type where oid=1043
set search path to public
deallocate pdo_stmt_0000000e
```

And then runs my query but I'm afraid that here is some impact in performance after migration. I have another 9.6 server with a fresh install no migration and it's not presenting that problem (response time). It seems to be expending too much time in those queries.

Do you have any tip or advice on how to fix this?

I did it with `pg_upgrade`, but I noticed that in the process some data doesn't migrate to v9.6 server. After that I did a dump/restore process and `vacuum analyze`.

Comment: try `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and compare between both servers

Comment: Those statements you are seeing are not "internal" statements of the Postgres server. This looks more like statements sent from your application (or a data access framework that is used by your application)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this is just doing a log in action for selecting a user permissions and other stof in order to render the main dashboard. It is making select over information_schema.coulmns table too, I'm not making those queries

Comment: Well, you might not be running those statement, but Postgres is not running them either. It must be something in your software stack.

Comment: Is there some way I could check that option?

Answer (score 2):

In our case, we neglected to:

`ANALYZE` the database

Postgres specifically might need it after a larger migration.

For example when upgrading django 2.2 to 3.2 and all of the `id` field types are changed from `AutoField` to `BigAutoField`

Answer (score 0):

you could install the pg_stat_statements extension on the slow and the fast system and compare the performance of the top queries in both systems. When there are major differences for the time/execution you can check the execution plans (using explain analyze).

Sometimes new features have a major performance impact after an upgrade. If my memory serves me well the parallel sequential scan - https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql96-parallel-sequential-scan/ - has been added in 9.6. Though this is basically a great feature, there are some situations in which its use may result in a slowdown of queries. This could be a reason to set parallel_setup_cost (or other planner parameters) to a different value to avoid inefficient parallel sequential scans.

Edited later: As I see in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/release-9-6.html the parallel query execution has not been activated by default, so it's probably not the reason of the slowdown in your situation. Still I think that only an analysis of the performance of the top queries and their plans may shed light on the issue.